# Is it possible to isolate spark cluster nodes for each individual application

Tags: apache-spark

We have a spark cluster comprising of 16 nodes. Is it possible to limit nodes 1 & 2 for application 'A'; nodes 3,4,5 for application 'B'; nodes 10,11,12,15 for application 'C'; and so on?

From the documentation, I understand that we can set some properties to control spark executor cores, number of executors to be launched, memories etc. But, I am curious to know if I can achieve the above use case.

Comment: Opinion: micromanaging doesn't scale :) That being said I would add information about the cluster manager you use. In standalone the answer is negative as far as I am aware. With YARN, Mesos and (upcoming) Kubernetes you might be able to find some hack.

Comment: @user6910411 It isn't a hack in YARN. Node labels are the feature that can be used.

Comment: @cricket_007 You can do the same in Mesos, but it is not the point. If you want statically allocate resources why use the same cluster? Like I said - opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious way to do that is to configure 3 different clusters with the desired topology, otherwise you're out of luck, spark does not have any provision,
because it is usually a bad idea and generally against the design principles of spark and clustering in general.  Why? If you assign application A to specific hosts, but it gets idle, while application B is running at 100%, you have 2 idle hosts that could be working for B, so you would be wasting costly computing resources. Usually, what you want is to assign a certain number of resources per application and let the system decide how to allocate them (scheduling.. plain spark is pretty elementary, but running under YARN and Mesos you can be more sophisticated).

Another reason why it's a bad idea is that you don't want rules that specify a specific host or set of hosts. What if you assign node 1&2 to application A and they both go down? Beside not using your resources efficiently, tying your app to specific hosts makes it also difficult to make them resilient to failure by rescheduling them on other hosts.

You may have other ways to do something similar though, if you're running spark under YARN or Mesos, you can define queues or quotas and limit the amount of resources that each application can use at a given time.

In general, it depends on the reason, why do you want to statically allocate resources to applications. If it's for resource management, you should instead looking at schedulers and queues. If it's for security, you should have multiple clusters, keeping in mind that you'd be losing in  performance.